# Opencv AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, opencv

That's what happened when I tried to use facial recognition on my raspberry PI
The following code:

```
#coding=utf-8
import cv2
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades+'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades+'haarcascade_eye.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame, 1.3, 5)
    img = frame
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        face_area = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(face_area)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(face_area,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),1)
    cv2.imshow('frame2',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_recognition1.py", line 4, in <module>
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades+'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'data'
```

python version:3.7.5
opencv version:3.4.3

Comment: try this: `cv2.samples.findFile("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")` does that return a valid path? -- how did you install the opencv package? the **official package** contains the `data` namespace. perhaps it's time to update... 3.4.3 is very old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your package of OpenCV is too old. You say it's v3.4.3. That is from 2018, so 3.5 years old.

Back then, the `data` namespace probably didn't exist yet.

**Update** the package.

Use the official package from PyPI: `pip3 install --upgrade opencv-python` (or just `pip` if you aren't on linux)

Do not use "OpenCV" packages from conda. At best they lag behind by half a year (conda-forge). At worst they're abandoned or potentially dangerous.

Comment: Thank you very much.I will try it again and upgrade my package

Answer (score -1):

Not sure where you got that, but you don't need them.  Just delete those:

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
```

Comment: delete what? `assert not face_cascade.empty()` that's gonna fail unless those xml files are in PATH (cwd in particular)... and they are PROBABLY not -- `cv2.data.haarcascades` was introduced because people had trouble finding them. I'd say that's needed. one can calculate those paths in other ways but those aren't as convenient.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it again.